# How to change a value for a key/value pair in an array in a handleChange function

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, onchange

I have a grid with a variable number of rows (dependent on the number of records) and 3-5 cards per grid row. We're using useSelector and .map to fill in the data for each of the cards; the initial state of the data has quite a few key/value pairs, some of which are unique to the record. In a console.log, it would look something like this:

```
[ 0: {Key: 1, PerformanceYR: "2019", SubRegionKey: 24, showDetail: false},
  1: {Key: 2, PerformanceYR: "2019", SubRegionKey: 24, showDetail: false},
  2: {Key: 3, PerformanceYR: "2019", SubRegionKey: 24, showDetail: false} ]
```

I've given each button an id that matches the key written like id={data.Key}. What I want to do with the handle change function is write it so that if the key for the button I'm clicking on matches a key in the data set, it will change "showDetail" in that record only from false to true (which in turn would render a new div with some additional details). I've been looking for hours, but I can't seem to figure it out. My current handleChange function is changing the values for all of the showDetails from false to true. The relevant pieces of code look like this:

```
const ServiceAreaTile = () => {
  const psOverviewSA = useSelector((state) => state.psOverviewSA);
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [detail, setDetail] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (event, data) => {
  let index = psOverviewSA.findIndex(item=> item.Key === 
  event.currentTarget.id)
  let newArray = [...psOverviewSA]
  setDetail(!newArray[index].showDetail)
  }

  return psOverviewSA.map((data) => {
  data.showDetail = detail;
  return (
  //a bunch of code for the grid, cards, etc.
```

Further down, there's a button that looks like this:

```
 <Button id={data.Key} 
 onClick={(event, data) => handleChange(event, data)} >
  <ExpandMoreIcon />
 </Button>
```

And then, finally, where the div is supposed to appear if the state of showDetail is true:

```
{data.showDetail && <div><Typography>{data.SubRegionKey}</Typography></div>}
```

I'm getting very frustrated by my inability to land on a solution for this, as it seems like it should be straightforward. Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

EDIT: I discovered that the above code works if I define the data set within the file above the main component and use useState within ServiceAreaTile instead of useSelector, but I really do need to use useSelector to bring in the data. Can someone provide an explanation of why the handleChange function as described above would work with useState and not useSelector?

Comment: please add a more complete code example of how `handleChanged` is used, what `setDetail` is, etc.

Comment: @thedude I've added some additional code - I believe all the relevant parts have been included now. Thank you!

Comment: where is `details` (stored using `useState`) used/read? If you could show more of your code that would help

Comment: @thedude sorry about that - I've added where it shows up right under the return statement (basically, the back end data doesn't have the "showDetail" key, so I've added it in the code for testing.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I needed to add the showDetail: false into the action that I was importing via the useSelector instead of trying to add it in my component file; as such, my action coded needed to look like this (see second-to-last line for "showDetail" addition):

```
import axiosconfig from "../../axiosconfig";
export const getpsOverviewSA = (performanceYR, subRegionKey) => async (
  dispatch
) => {
  const response = await axiosconfig.get("/api/psOverviewSA", {
    params: { performanceYR, subRegionKey },
  });
  dispatch({ type: "GET_PS_OVERVIEW_SA", payload: response.data, showDetail: false });
};
```

Now it works perfectly.